# Jmeter random variable function for specific alpha numeric pattern

Tags: random, jmeter, web-api-testing

I am new to Jmeter. I am testing rest API using Jmeter. In one scenario need to pass dynamic random variable in request. The pattern is starting character should be an alphabet and remaining 9 characters numbers (0-9) example "J123456789". Please suggest me how to do it using Jmeter random functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) and [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) functions combination like:

```
${__RandomString(1,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,)}${__Random(111111111,999999999,)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/)